# TypeScript in WebStorm can not see classes from typings folder

Tags: typescript, webstorm

TypeScript in WebStorm can not see classes from typings folder.

When I do `import Engine = BABYLON.Engine;` WebStorm say "unresolved variable or type BABYLON".

Option "resolve objects using tsconfig.json" in settings enabled.

Folder structure:

```
├── angular-cli-build.js
├── angular-cli.json
├── config
├── dist
├── e2e
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── public
├── src
├── tmp
├── tslint.json
├── typings
└── typings.json
```

Comment: try to use var Engine = BABYLON.Engine;

Comment: what do you typings.json and tsconfig.json look like? I have been unable to install babylonjs via typings - seems the corresponding module is not in the registry

Comment: To use BABYLON I add 

    {
      ...
      "ambientDependencies": {
        ...
        "babylonjs": "github:BabylonJS/Babylon.js/dist/babylon.2.3.d.ts"
      }
    }

in typings.json.

Comment: `var Engine = BABYLON.Engine;` doesn't help.